# Issue with cross-validation using the automap package

Tags: r, gstat, spatial-interpolation, automap, geor

I want to do a cross-validation for the ca20-Dataset from the geoR
                package. With for example the meuse-dataset, this works fine, but for
                this dataset, I encounter a strange problem with the dimensions of the
                SpatialPointsDataFrame. Maybe you can try this for yourself and explain
                why the autoKrige.cv function does not work (I tried several
                nfold-values but this only changes the locations-value of the error
                message...):

```
library(geoR)
library(gstat)
library(automap)
data(ca20)
east=ca20$coords[,1]
north=ca20$coords[,2]
concentration=ca20$data
frame=data.frame(east,north)
data=data.frame(concentration)
points<-SpatialPoints(data.frame(east,north),proj4string=CRS(as.character(NA)))
pointsframe<-SpatialPointsDataFrame(points,data, coords.nrs = numeric(0),proj4string = CRS(as.character(NA)), match.ID = TRUE)
krig=autoKrige(pointsframe$concentration~1,pointsframe)
plot(krig)
cv=autoKrige.cv(pointsframe$concentration~1,pointsframe)
```

I hope someone can reproduce the problem, my R version is 2.15, all packages are up to date (at least not older than a month or so...).

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Note that `gstat`, and thus `automap` are not designed to work with non-projected data, so please check if this is the case or not. It seems your data is not projected...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the way you build your SpatialPointsDataFrame can be done more easily:

```
library(geoR)
library(gstat)
library(automap)
```

...and build the SPDF:

```
pointsframe = data.frame(ca20$coords)
pointsframe$concentration = ca20$data
coordinates(pointsframe) = c("east", "north")
```

The problem you have is in how you use the `formula` argument. You add the spatial object `pointsframe` to the formula, in essence putting a vector directly into the formula. You should just use the column name in the formula, like this:

```
cv=autoKrige.cv(concentration~1,pointsframe)
```

and it works:

```
> summary(cv)
            [,1]      
mean_error  -0.01134  
me_mean     -0.0002237
MAE         6.02      
MSE         60.87     
MSNE        1.076     
cor_obspred 0.7081    
cor_predres 0.01343   
RMSE        7.802     
RMSE_sd     0.7041    
URMSE       7.802     
iqr         9.519
```